# Filter array of objects on key from array of values JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects [{...}, {...}] with 2 objects inside. I would like to filter them with values from an array using JavaScript. The inital object could be any length from 1 to n. I think I need to filter on the key from the json data in a loop using .includes()

This is a mess but I think this needs to be inside another loop for the length of jsonData

```
          for (i=0; i<finalArray.length; i++){
            jsonData= Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(jsonData).filter(([key, value]) => key.includes(finalArray[i])) )
          }
```

```
0: { "cbsa_cde": "33460", "cbsa_nm": "Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington, MN-WI", "countycode": "27053", "hh_50k_100k_201612": 71, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 86, "hh_50k_100k_201712": 60, "hh_50k_100k_201806": 37, "hh_50k_100k_201812": 49, "hh_50k_100k_201906": 35, "hh_50k_100k_201912": 38, "hh_50k_100k_202006": 46, "hh_50k_100k_202012": 58, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 120, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 121, "hh_100k_250k_201712": 153, "hh_100k_250k_201806": 126, "hh_100k_250k_201812": 126, "hh_100k_250k_201906": 125, "hh_100k_250k_201912": 120, "hh_100k_250k_202006": 99, "hh_100k_250k_202012": 84}   

1: { "cbsa_cde": "33460", "cbsa_nm": "Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington, MN-WI", "countycode": "27053","hh_50k_100k_201612": 20, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 33, "hh_50k_100k_201712": 22, "hh_50k_100k_201806": 41, "hh_50k_100k_201812": 52, "hh_50k_100k_201906": 45, "hh_50k_100k_201912": 40, "hh_50k_100k_202006": 41, "hh_50k_100k_202012": 50, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 99, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 108, "hh_100k_250k_201712": 130, "hh_100k_250k_201806": 84, "hh_100k_250k_201812": 90, "hh_100k_250k_201906": 97, "hh_100k_250k_201912": 89, "hh_100k_250k_202006": 95, "hh_100k_250k_202012": 87}
```

The array I would like to use as a filter

```
FilterArray = [ "HH_50K_100K_201612", "HH_50K_100K_201706", "HH_100K_250K_201612", "HH_100K_250K_201706" ]
```

Final output would be best if it modifies the original.

```
jsonData= 
0: {"hh_50k_100k_201612": 71, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 86, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 120, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 121}   

1: {"hh_50k_100k_201612": 20, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 33, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 99, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 108}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want to get some keys in an object, and these keys would be in an array, right ? Or maybe you want to delete these keys ?

Comment: My read on the question is that the aim is to mutate the two objects ( { cbsa_code: ...}) removing all keys except for those appearing in FilterArray. Is that correct?

Comment: This is correct keep only what is in filterArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map()` to loop over the array of objects and create a new array with the result of filtering the object properties.

You should be using `FilterArray.includes()`, not `key.includes()`.

```js
const finalArray = [ { "cbsa_cde": "33460", "cbsa_nm": "Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington, MN-WI", "countycode": "27053", "hh_50k_100k_201612": 71, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 86, "hh_50k_100k_201712": 60, "hh_50k_100k_201806": 37, "hh_50k_100k_201812": 49, "hh_50k_100k_201906": 35, "hh_50k_100k_201912": 38, "hh_50k_100k_202006": 46, "hh_50k_100k_202012": 58, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 120, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 121, "hh_100k_250k_201712": 153, "hh_100k_250k_201806": 126, "hh_100k_250k_201812": 126, "hh_100k_250k_201906": 125, "hh_100k_250k_201912": 120, "hh_100k_250k_202006": 99, "hh_100k_250k_202012": 84}, { "cbsa_cde": "33460", "cbsa_nm": "Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington, MN-WI", "countycode": "27053","hh_50k_100k_201612": 20, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 33, "hh_50k_100k_201712": 22, "hh_50k_100k_201806": 41, "hh_50k_100k_201812": 52, "hh_50k_100k_201906": 45, "hh_50k_100k_201912": 40, "hh_50k_100k_202006": 41, "hh_50k_100k_202012": 50, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 99, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 108, "hh_100k_250k_201712": 130, "hh_100k_250k_201806": 84, "hh_100k_250k_201812": 90, "hh_100k_250k_201906": 97, "hh_100k_250k_201912": 89, "hh_100k_250k_202006": 95, "hh_100k_250k_202012": 87} ],
      filterArray = [ "HH_50K_100K_201612", "HH_50K_100K_201706", "HH_100K_250K_201612", "HH_100K_250K_201706" ];

const result = finalArray.map(jsonData =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(jsonData).filter(([key, value]) => filterArray.includes(key.toUpperCase()))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I dont know which is better but I can read this one a bit better so I am accepting this on thank you!

Comment: The difference is if there are any strings in `filterArray` that aren't keys in `finalArray`. The other answer will create those properties in the result with `undefined` as the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` with `Object.fromEntries()`. Iterate over each object and map over key of `filterArray` and generate the resultant object.

```js
const data = [ { "cbsa_cde": "33460", "cbsa_nm": "Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington, MN-WI", "countycode": "27053", "hh_50k_100k_201612": 71, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 86, "hh_50k_100k_201712": 60, "hh_50k_100k_201806": 37, "hh_50k_100k_201812": 49, "hh_50k_100k_201906": 35, "hh_50k_100k_201912": 38, "hh_50k_100k_202006": 46, "hh_50k_100k_202012": 58, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 120, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 121, "hh_100k_250k_201712": 153, "hh_100k_250k_201806": 126, "hh_100k_250k_201812": 126, "hh_100k_250k_201906": 125, "hh_100k_250k_201912": 120, "hh_100k_250k_202006": 99, "hh_100k_250k_202012": 84}, { "cbsa_cde": "33460", "cbsa_nm": "Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington, MN-WI", "countycode": "27053","hh_50k_100k_201612": 20, "hh_50k_100k_201706": 33, "hh_50k_100k_201712": 22, "hh_50k_100k_201806": 41, "hh_50k_100k_201812": 52, "hh_50k_100k_201906": 45, "hh_50k_100k_201912": 40, "hh_50k_100k_202006": 41, "hh_50k_100k_202012": 50, "hh_100k_250k_201612": 99, "hh_100k_250k_201706": 108, "hh_100k_250k_201712": 130, "hh_100k_250k_201806": 84, "hh_100k_250k_201812": 90, "hh_100k_250k_201906": 97, "hh_100k_250k_201912": 89, "hh_100k_250k_202006": 95, "hh_100k_250k_202012": 87} ],
      filterArray = [ "HH_50K_100K_201612", "HH_50K_100K_201706", "HH_100K_250K_201612", "HH_100K_250K_201706" ],
      result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(filterArray.map(key => [key.toLowerCase(), o[key.toLowerCase()]])));
console.log(result);
```